# Menu items with different width

Tags: html, css

All my menu items have a 150px width but I would like to decrease the width of some of them (ie. News & Media). Was thinking of something like this:

```
#menu.smallerwidth ul li {
    width: 100px;
}
```

but not sure if this is the correct method and how to reflect that in ly html code.
Many thanks for your help

See http://jsfiddle.net/JTxVt/

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h5>ESPACE dgddsgd</h5>
          <ul>
            <li><a title="" href="">+ Cabinet dgds</a> </li>
            <li><a title="" href="">+ Ateliers dgd</a> </li>
          </ul>
        <li>
          <h5>ESPACE dsgs</h5>
          <ul>
            <li><a title="" href="">+ dgds dsgs</a> </li>
            <li><a title="" href="">+ hffh de dfh</a> </li>
            <li><a title="" href="">+ d d'fdhfdfhfdh</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h5>NEWS & MEDIA</h5>
          <ul>
            <li><a title="" href="">+ hghgfh</a> </li>
            <li><a title="" href="">+ ghgfhfgg</a> </li>
            <li><a title="" href="">+ ghgfhgf</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h5>LE hgfg</h5>
          <ul>
            <li><a title="" href="">+ L'hghgf</a> </li>
            <li><a title="" href="">+ ghgf</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#menu {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 31px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#menu ul {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    color: #000;
    list-style: none;

}
#menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    line-height: 20px;

}

#menu.smallerwidth ul li {
    width: 100px;
}



#menu>ul>li {
    margin-left: 20px;

}
#menu ul li a { /* This is the sub-menu items */
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 12px; 
    padding-left: 10px;
}
#menu ul li a, #menu ul ul:hover li a {
    color: #333;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -moz-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -ms-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -o-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -webkit-transition-property: all, -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: all, -moz-transform;
    -ms-transition-property: all, -ms-transform;
    -o-transition-property: all, -o-transform;
    transition-property: all, transform;
}
#menu ul ul li a:hover, #menu ul ul li.current-menu-item a {
    color: #005EBC;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -moz-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -ms-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -o-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -webkit-transition-property: all, -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: all, -moz-transform;
    -ms-transition-property: all, -ms-transform;
    -o-transition-property: all, -o-transform;
    transition-property: all, transform;
}

    h5 {
        margin-bottom: 3px;
        color: #FFF;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 11px; /* This is the top menu items */
        background: #0064C4;
        padding-left: 10px;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing a whitespace between the container's ID and the class of the children.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/JTxVt/1/)

```
#menu .smallerwidth ul li {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Good point thanks! Would you know why the width of the menu item headers (the ones with blue background) doesn't change? I tried to apply the class "smallerwidth" to <ul> but without success. Tks